# Regex negative lookahead for an IP address

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm currently using this to match IP addresses.

```
preg_match('/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/ ', $_POST['the-value'])
```

Trying to flip it up for backend validation and just looking for some help on the where, how, and why to place the ?! to turn this into a negative lookahead. Been using a online regex tester trying all kinds of variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make use of [`FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) under the PHP's [`filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) functions ?

```
<?php
$ip='123.43.55.22';
if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
echo "IP is valid. This can be inserted into the table !";
}
```

Comment: I have no rebuttal for that question lol. I remember switching the preg_match out for that function one point too now that I see it again, I can't recall why I didn't stay with it. Thx!